# sum of number printing it in macro and in main gives me different output, i'm beginner to macro

Tags: c

I'm trying to print sum of numbers in macro as well in main, but don't know why i'm getting the different output with printing it in main.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define sum(a,b)\
printf("\n%d",a+b)


int main() {
    sum(2,4);
 printf("\nsum in main = %d",sum(2,4));
return 0;
}
```

output:

```
6
6
sum in main = 2
```

looks like it is printing the number of char present in marco.
If i comment the printf in macro, then printf in main works fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define sum(a,b) a+b
//printf("\n%d",a+b)


int main() {
 //   sum(2,4);
 printf("\nsum in main = %d",sum(2,4));
return 0;
}
```

output:

```
sum in main = 6
```

Comment: Do you understand your code snippets are not equivalent?

Comment: Use gcc -E to see what the macro expands to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("\nsum in main = %d",sum(2,4));
```

In the first case the `printf` is printing the return value of `printf` which is the number of characters printed.

`printf` is expecting the value for format specifier `%d` , the value is the return value of `printf` which is from the macro.

The other case `%d` is getting value `6` from the macro `sum(2,4)`

Comment: Thanks, i got it. The explanation is pure clear. Stack Overflow is OSM.

Answer (score 2):

first, you should declare your macro as:

```
#define sum(a,b) ((a)+(b))
```

second, it works perfectly fine, the issue is, that in first example you defined `sum` as

`#define sum(a,b) printf("\n%d", a+b)`

so this macro will just print sum of `a+b` and then return printf value, which is count of characters printed, in this case `2` because you print newline (`\n`) and result of sum (`6`), so in your case after unwrapping macro your code looks like:

`printf("sum in main = %d\n", printf("\n%d", a+b));`
that's why it's printing 2 at the end - you just pass result of function `printf` to another `printf`